# Unit 4.5.4 Xcode project landscape Mode ScreenOrientation in ios 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, ios8

Any help,
Thanks

Am facing one issue in Unity 4.5.4 Xcode project.

how to lock  landscape Mode ScreenOrientation in ios 8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ScreenOrientation ConvertToUnityScreenOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation hwOrient,EnabledOrientation* outAutorotOrient){
    EnabledOrientation autorotOrient     = autorotPortrait;
    ScreenOrientation  unityScreenOrient = portrait;
    switch (hwOrient)
    {   case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            autorotOrient     = autorotPortrait;
            unityScreenOrient = portrait;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            autorotOrient     = autorotPortraitUpsideDown;
            unityScreenOrient = portraitUpsideDown;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            autorotOrient     = autorotLandscapeRight;
            unityScreenOrient = landscapeRight;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            autorotOrient     = autorotLandscapeLeft;
            unityScreenOrient = landscapeLeft;
            break;
    }
   if (outAutorotOrient)
        *outAutorotOrient = autorotOrient;

    return portrait; // Now works in Landscape >.<
}
```

Comment: We can use this method, i cant format this answer Sorry